# Python 3.8.3 incompatible with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I recently installed python with the version 3.8.3 and upgraded pip to 20.1.1. According to [enter link description here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-install), `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow` should work. However, I get this result

```
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - tensorflow -> python[version='3.5.*|3.6.*|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|3.7.*']

Your python: python=3.8

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
```

since I use

```
(base) C:\Users\ivan>python --version
Python 3.8.3

(base) C:\Users\ivan>pip --version
pip 20.1.1 from C:\Users\ivan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
```

I wonder if it is possible to solve this issue without downgrading.  For users of anaconda 2020.07, python 3.8 is used by default. Downgrading it will break anaconda.

Answer (score 2):

People have reported  problems using tensorflow with python 3.8, it is best to use 3.7.  You are incorrect about breaking Anaconda. Here is what to do.
In Anaconda home page click on environments. At the bottom left of the page click on create. A window will appear. Give the new environment a name (say python3.7). In the drop down menu select 3.7. Now a new environment is created using python 3.7. Now in the conda terminal type conda activate python3.7. Then use conda to install tensorflow. It will install version 2.1.1, the cuda toolkit version 10.1.243 and cudnn version 7.6.5. Note conda can only install tensorflow up to version 2.1.1. If you want tensorflow 2.2 install it with pip using pip install tensorflow ==2.2.0.  after you have installed 2.1. The cuda toolkit and cudnn work with version 2.2. Now use pip or conda to install any other packages you need in your python3.7 environment and you should be good to go!